# reload dataTable with previous settings

Tags: jquery, datatable

This is my dataTable settings:

```
$("#order_items").dataTable({
  sDom: "<'row-fluid'r>t",
  bProcessing: true,
  sScrollX: "100%",
  bScrollCollapse: true,
  bAutoWidth: false,
  iDisplayLength: 25,
  aaSorting: [[1, "desc"]],
  aoColumns: [
    {
      sWidth: "150px"
    }, {
      sWidth: "400px"
    }, {
      sWidth: "40px"
    }, {
      sWidth: "50px"
    }, {
      sWidth: "100px"
    }, {
      sWidth: "100px"
    }
  ],
  bServerSide: true,
  oLanguage: {
    sUrl: $('#order_items').data('datatable')
  },
  sAjaxSource: $('#order_items').data('source'),
  aoColumnDefs: [
    {
      bSortable: false,
      aTargets: ["unsortable"]
    }
  ]
}).fnSetFilteringDelay();
```

When i run `$('#order_items').DataTable().ajax.reload()` I lose the previous settings. I would like recovery the previous settings to show dataTable

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use below code  . create datatable  with object  .

```
var tblObject = $("#order_items").dataTable({ // your settings
```

And call ajax reload function using

```
 tblObject.ajax.reload();
```

read more about [ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29)

Comment: This fix does work fine if call to reload dataTable in the same script. However I use rails. The first settings is loaded in my assets coffescripts files. After to reload the dataDatable, I create other file `update.js.erb`, so I can not access to local variable `tblObject`. Thank you

Comment: ohhh i dot't have to much knowledge rails sorry abt that :)